# AWS S3 React app with Cloudfront distribution broken routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-router, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

I have a React app hosted on S3 as a static website and a Cloudfront Web Distribution that points the the S3 address. 
I can guarantee that the distribution is set up correctly, with the 404 and 403 Error pages redirect to 'index.html'.

The problem I still encounter is routing which redirects to the `<S3-url>/index.html` instead of `<Cloudfront-url>/` when I try to get to a different route than root.

One thing I've noticed is that the **Restrict Bucket Access** option is not available any more on the **Origin** tab of the Cloudfront dashboard.

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: "Restrict Bucket Access" is not applicable when using the static web site hosting feature, because the static web site endpoints don't support origin access identities.  As for troubleshooting, can you share the URL?  Have you configured any actual routing rules on the bucket itself?

Comment: Only the `/login` route redirected to the S3 bucket url, after using `/log-in` the issue wouldn’t replicate anymore. Might be a bug from AWS.

Comment: I don't expect it's a bug in AWS.  If your rewrite rules in S3 don't test `<HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>`, then they can match pages that they shouldn't, and can give you a redirect loop.  Also, newly-created bucket will sometimes give you redirects to the bucket URL for a few minutes after it is first created, but that is expected behavior, because the traffic may be temporarily routed to the wrong S3 facility until the auto-created, custom DNS records that route traffic to your bucket via `*.s3.amazonaws.com` replace the default records. Not enough info here to say for sure what happened.

Comment: I haven't set the rewrite rules in S3, but as Cloudfront redirects in _Error Pages_. Also the bucket and distribution is a couple of months old.

Comment: Can you provide the CloudFront and bucket URLs?  If not, you can send them [to me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot?tab=profile) and I'll respond here with what I find.

Comment: I can't, sorry, thanks for your help!